# How to resize a rectangle to fit a device in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have a rectangle in a frame as shown below

[Rectangle in iPhone 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05kF5.png)

[Rectangle in iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O4g3.png)

I am trying to proportionally adjust the height of rectangle so that there is an equal proportion of white in every iPhone model, but as is clearly visible the rectangle takes over the entire screen in a smaller iPhone model.

I am sure SwiftUI has a formal feature that allows for the rectangle to be resized proportionally.

How can I do this? Code shown below

```
         VStack {
            ZStack {
                //Rectangle 12
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
                    .frame(width: 391, height: 800)
                
                
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
```

EDIT: It seems like my question, while describing what I want in isolation did not truly encapsulate what I want

I want to create this design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDmHe.png)

However, I want it to scale properly across devices.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what a `GeometryReader` is for. It reads the size given to it, in this case the whole screen. Then, you can put a `.frame()` on the `Spacer` which is a compressible view to keep it at a set size. In the example code below, it is 10% of the view height.

```
struct ProportionalRectangle: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7137255072593689, green: 0.10196077823638916, blue: 0.10196077823638916, alpha: 1)))
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find any article that mentions this solution - Im not arguing against its validity, but this problem is so simple that Im curious why no article seems to have a solution for it let alone this specific solution. Any reason why?

Comment: @erchispatwardhan in SwiftUI, if you need proportionally-sized views, you need to use `GeometryReader`. However in most cases you **do not** want proportionally-sized views, or big views that have both a hardcoded width and height. Are you trying to make a white tab bar? In that case, set the height of the tab bar to `.frame(height: 80)` and then the red rectangle will automatically expand.

Comment: The reason you haven't read this particular solution isn't that a `GeometryReader` is unusual. It is more that this question is. I wrote the solution based on the question. Most people don't use a `Rectangle()` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to divide the view into red rectangle and white.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]